# .NET: 100% CPU usage in HttpClient because of Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary, dotnet-httpclient

**Short Question:**
Has anyone else encountered an issue in using a singleton .NET HttpClient where the application pegs the processor at 100% until it's restarted?

**Details:**
I'm running a Windows Service that does continuous, schedule-based ETL. One of the data-syncing threads occasionally either just dies, or starts running out of control and pegs the processor at 100%.

I was lucky enough to see this happening live before someone simply restarted the service (the standard fix), and was able to grab a dump-file.

Loading this in WinDbg (w/ SOS and SOSEX), I found that I have about 15 threads (sub-tasks of the main processing thread) all running with identical stack-traces. However, there don't appear to be any deadlocks. I.E. the high-utilization threads are running, but never finishing.

The relevant stack-trace segment follows (addresses omitted):

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].FindEntry(System.__Canon)
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.__Canon, mscorlib],[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryGetValue(System.__Canon, System.__Canon ByRef)
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ContainsParsedValue(System.String, System.Object)
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpGeneralHeaders.get_TransferEncodingChunked()
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpGeneralHeaders.AddSpecialsFrom(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpGeneralHeaders)
System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpRequestHeaders.AddHeaders(System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders)
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
...
[Our Application Code]
```

According to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/12/21/high-cpu-in-net-app-using-a-static-generic-dictionary/) (and others I've found), the use of dictionaries is *not* thread-safe, and infinite loops are possible (as are straight-up crashes) if you access a dictionary in a multi-threaded manner.

**BUT** our application code is not using a dictionary explicitly. So where is the dictionary mentioned in the stack-trace?

Following through via .NET Reflector, it *appears* that the HttpClient uses a dictionary to store any values that have been configured in the "DefaultRequestHeaders" property. Any request the gets sent through the HttpClient, therefore, triggers an enumeration of a singleton, non-thread-safe dictionary (in order to add the default headers to the request), which could potentially infinitely spin (or kill) the threads involved if a corruption occurs.

Microsoft has stated bluntly that the HttpClient class is thread-safe. But it seems to me like this is no longer true if any headers have been added to the DefaultRequestHeaders of the HttpClient.

My analysis seems to indicate that this is the real root problem, and an easy workaround is to simply never use the DefaultRequestHeaders where the HttpClient could be used in a multi-threaded manner.

However, I'm looking for some confirmation that I'm not barking up the wrong tree. If this is correct, it seems like a bug in the .NET framework, which I automatically tend to doubt.

Sorry for the wordy question, but thanks for any input you may have.

Comment: this is their standard spiel with thread safty: "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe."

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why make the Http client a singleton? It seems to me the easiest fix would be to simply let each thread create and use its own instance.

Comment: I see your point, but the basic operation of an HttpClient is "SendAsync", which is not a static member. As for a MCV example, I'll see if I can create a PoC of the issue and post it if/when I can.

Comment: @pquest: Refer to [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/single-instance-of-reusable-httpclient) for details on why to singleton the HttpClient.

Comment: I don't see anything about thread safety on msdn and the one quote from the msdn forums by the designer says "HttpClient instance is a kind of "session" which share configuration options as well as underlying TCP connections" which for me implied it's only safe as long as you don't change the configuration. Which is what you do and which fits your description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments; they got me thinking along different lines, and helped me find the ultimate root cause of the issue.

Although the issue *was* a result of corruption in the backing dictionary of the DefaultRequestHeaders, the real culprit was the initialization code for the HttpClient object:

```
private HttpClient InitializeClient()
{
    if (_client == null)
    {
        _client = GetHttpClient();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        SetBaseAddress(BaseAddress);
    }
    return _client;
}
```

I said that the HttpClient was a singleton, which is partially incorrect. It's created as a single-instance that is shared amongst multiple threads doing a unit of work, and is disposed when the work is complete. A new instance will be spun up the next time this particular task must be done.

The "InitializeClient" method above is called every time a request is to be sent, and should just short-circuit due to the "_client" field not being null after the first run-through.

(Note that this isn't being done in the object's constructor because it's an abstract class, and "GetHttpClient" is an abstract method -- BTW: don't ever call an abstract method in a base-class's constructor... that causes other nightmares)

Of course, it's fairly obvious that this isn't thread-safe, and the resultant behavior is non-deterministic.

The fix is to put this code behind a double-checked "lock" statement (although I will be eliminating the use of the "DefaultRequestHeaders" property anyways, just because).

*In a nutshell, my original question shouldn't ever be an issue if you're careful in how you initialize the HttpClient.*

Thanks for the clarity of thought that you all provided!

Comment: This is a classic threading problem. The hash table becomes cyclic due to races. An infinite collision so to speak. I did not see your question or I would have answered.

Comment: @usr: No worries; I'm just glad to a get a good explanation as to the cause. :)